# problem with serbian italics

Tags: italic, cyrillic

I have a problem with Serbian italics

I have this text, for example:

[image]

when I put the name of the book in italics without setting language (Serbian), everything is ok:

[image]

but when I set Serbian, I get this:

[image]

does anybody know where is the problem? I'm using polyglossia package and Linux Libertine. thank you

EDIT:

picture 1: `ИВИЋ,\,П.: Преглед историје српског језика. Сремски Карловци~– Нови Сад 1998.`

picture 2: `ИВИЋ,\,П.: \textit{Преглед историје српског језика.} Сремски Карловци~– Нови Сад 1998.`

picture 3: `\textserbian{ИВИЋ,\,П.: \textit{Преглед историје српског језика.} Сремски Карловци~– Нови Сад 1998.}`

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of TeX code?

Comment: The Linux Libertine font has that variant of italic Cyrillic “d” for Serbian. Not sure if you can do anything lest than pretending the language is different.

Comment: @egreg -- i understand the "d", but not the "g", which is the fourth letter in the same word.  it looks like an undotted "i" with either an overbar or a dieresis.

Comment: yes, there is a problem with letter г and п. its macron, I think

Comment: @barbarabeeton I just saw the “d”; writing it in the shape of a Latin “g” is not so strange, perhaps. Surely the “g” and the “p’ are at least very dubious.

Comment: @egreg -- oops!  didn't even spot the "p".  that's just plain wrong!  i think a bug report is in order.

Comment: These forms are the correct ones for Serbian italics, cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbian_Cyrillic_alphabet#Differences_from_other_Cyrillic_alphabets If you don't like them you can change them to the variant used in other cyrillic scripts as described in the answer below, but this is definitely *not* a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a precise choice of the font designers. When the language tag is set to SRB, the following substitutions are made in the italic font

[image]

I guess this is to imitate handwriting; the CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER PE U+403F is drawn like a “u”, with the macron to represent that the bridge should be at the top (something similar is made in Sütterlin Schrift). Similarly for CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER GHE U+0433, while CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER DE U+0434 is drawn as it is common in handwriting, as far as I know.

You can disable this with a kludge

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{serbian}
\setmainfont[RawFeature={language=DFLT}]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

ИВИЋ,\,П.: \textit{Преглед историје српског језика.} Сремски Карловци~– Нови Сад 1998.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! I set language to Bulgarian and everything works well now, too

Comment: moved from @user75801's answer: Thanks for your suggestion. I open [a new question.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237673/difference-between-russian-and-serbian-cyrillic-italic-letter) If anybody can help, I will grateful.