# Difference between Russian and Serbian Cyrillic italic letter

Tags: letters

I also have a question about Serbian Cyrillic latter in latex. So I write some code in latex to have Serbian (Latin and Cyrillic) and English language in a same document. Fortunately, in my case when I transform to italic I got Russian Cyrillic letter.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[serbian,english]{babel}
%\usepackage{serbian-def-cyr}
\input{cyracc.def}
\newcommand\textcyr[1]{{\fontencoding{OT2}\fontfamily{wncyr}\selectfont #1}}

\begin{document}

Text in English.\\ \textit{Ili probaću da pišem kako treba latiničnim pismom.}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{serbian}
\textcyr{\cyracc ja bih bio tamo gde je deda voleo biti. Gde \'ce biti deda?}

\textit{\textcyr{\cyracc ja bih bio tamo gde je deda voleo biti}}
\end{otherlanguage*}

A word and another 
\foreignlanguage{serbian}{\textcyr{\cyracc \textit{slovo}}}

\end{document}
```

and I got this:

[image]

but I would like to have g, d, p and t latter on Serbian Cyrillic like on picture:

[image]

Also I'm interested in how can I use just one letter to define one letter in Cyrillic. So here I make alphabet, but I would like to write just š instead sh, or ć instead \'c... etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\input{cyracc.def}
\newcommand\textcyr[1]{{\fontencoding{OT2}\fontfamily{wncyr}\selectfont #1}}
\begin{document}
Serbian alphabet again \dots \textcyr{\cyracc
A B V G D DJ E Zh Z I J K L LJ M N NJ O P R S T \'C U F Kh C Ch \Dzh\ Sh
}
\textcyr{\cyracc \\Ja sam bio kod babe i dede. Tako sam pokushao da uradim neshto lepo.
\\a b v g d dj e zh z i j k l lj m n nj o p r s t \'c u f kh c ch \dzh\ sh}
```

Any help!? Thanks!

Comment: Didn't we have this question yesterday? No, something different, related though: [problem with serbian italics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237676)

Comment: Yes, but I was add as a comment on another question with similar topic, and not as a single issue. That was the reason of posting this problem again as a question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The `wncyr` fonts don't support the Serbian variants for italic letters. Only a few OpenType fonts do: Linux Libertine, Old Standard and EB Garamond, for instance. But they require typesetting with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: the definitions in `cyracc.def` were intended for use with the `wncyr` fonts, which , as @egreg says, don't support the serbian variants for italic letters.  these definitions were devised for a specific purpose: to implement the math reviews conventions for cyrillic transliteration, based on plain tex requirements as of the early 1980s.  no single-letter input is possible, nor is it likely to be; `cyracc.def` should be considered an obsolete artifact, and should be used only for reprocessing existing old documents.

Answer (score 3):

The Washington University fonts for Cyrillic don't support variant shapes of letters for Serbian.

There is no font available for `pdflatex` that does, as far as I know.

Some OpenType fonts *do* support variant shapes for Serbian in the italic font, notably Linux Libertine, Old Standard an EB Garamond, but they need XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

You may not be satisfied by the shapes though, but this is just stylistic choice.

For inputting Serbian with the AMS transliteration scheme in XeLaTeX, you can follow my answer at [Serbian Cyrillic using LuaTeX and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44709/serbian-cyrillic-using-luatex-and-xetex)

Here's an example document using Old Standard:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}

\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\newfontfamily{\serbianfont}{Old Standard}[
  Mapping=ascii-to-serbian,
  Script=Cyrillic,
  Language=Serbian,
]

\begin{document}

Serbian alphabet again \textserbian{%
A B V G D DJ E Zh Z I J K L LJ M N NJ O P R S T C1 U F Kh C Ch Dzh Sh \\
Ja sam bio kod babe i dede. Tako sam pokushao da uradim neshto lepo. \\
a b v g d dj e zh z i j k l lj m n nj o p r s t c1 u f kh c ch dzh sh}

Also \textserbian{'C 'c D1 d1}

\itshape

Serbian alphabet again \textserbian{%
A B V G D DJ E Zh Z I J K L LJ M N NJ O P R S T C1 U F Kh C Ch Dzh Sh \\
Ja sam bio kod babe i dede. Tako sam pokushao da uradim neshto lepo. \\
a b v g d dj e zh z i j k l lj m n nj o p r s t c1 u f kh c ch dzh sh}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same, but with EB Garamond instead:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cmsrb](https://ctan.org/pkg/cmsrb) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmsrb}
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand\textcyr[1]{{\fontencoding{OT2}\selectfont #1}}

\begin{document}

Serbian alphabet again \dots \textcyr{
A B V G D Đ E Ž Z I J K L LJ M N NJ O P R S T Ć U F H C Č DŽ Š
}
\textcyr{ \\ Ja sam bio kod babe i dede. Tako sam pokušao da uradim nešto lepo.
\\a b v g d đ e ž z i j k l lj m n nj o p r s t ć u f h c č dž š }

\itshape

Serbian alphabet again \dots \textcyr{
A B V G D Đ E Ž Z I J K L LJ M N NJ O P R S T Ć U F H C Č DŽ Š
}
\textcyr{ \\ Ja sam bio kod babe i dede. Tako sam pokušao da uradim nešto lepo.
\\a b v g d đ e ž z i j k l lj m n nj o p r s t ć u f h c č dž š }

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: cmsrb example]