# Text processor for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, ebgaramond

For my case, I'm interested in this EB Garamond font type. Because I have not yet used LaTeX very long, can you help me to recommend me which TeX text processor I can use to make this second type font? Or do you know whether I can make this type of font in some cloud (online) processor?

I should use XeLaTeX of LuaLaTeX.

This question is a continuation of this topic: [Difference between Russian and Serbian Cyrillic italic letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237673/difference-between-russian-and-serbian-cyrillic-italic-letter/237779#237779)

Comment: See also [How do I use an OpenType font with my LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46/35864) and [Installing TTF fonts in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226/35864)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "text processor"? Which TeX distribution do you have so far? Any up-to-date TeXLive or MikTeX distribution should have LuaLateX, XeLaTeX, and the full suite of EG Garamond fonts in OpenType format installed and ready to go.

Comment: Yes, I think which TeX distribution I should use. Thanks!

Comment: There are two main distributions, no matter which system you are running on, TeX Live will be available.

Answer (score 2):

Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[script=Cyrillic]{serbian}

\newrobustcmd{\latinserbian}[1]{%
  \foreignlanguage{serbian}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

Text in English.

\latinserbian{\textit{Ili probaću da pišem kako treba latiničnim pismom.}}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{serbian}
ја бих био тамо где је деда волео бити. Где ће бити деда?

\textit{ја бих био тамо где је деда волео бити}
\end{otherlanguage*}

A word and another
\foreignlanguage{serbian}{slovo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. LuaLaTeX, happily, produces the same output in this case as XeLaTeX does.